# Cypher: extract only nodes with independent connections to two other nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following query:

```
MATCH (rebecca:Person)-[r1*1..3]-(robert:Person)
WHERE rebecca.name=Rebecca AND robert.name='Robert'
RETURN rebecca, robert,
  extract(x IN r1 | {rel: x, start: startNode(x), end: endNode(x)})
```

This returns all the nodes and edges within 3 hops of **both** Rebecca or Robert. So it includes some nodes that are 2 hops from Rebecca, and 3 hops from Robert, where his connection is via Rebecca.

Is there a way I can exclude the nodes for which Robert's only connection is via Rebecca, and vice versa?

I'm interested in connections that they truly share independently, not where the only connection is via each other.

Comment: Can you give an example of a path you currently see that you don't want to be considered? In that path, does Rebecca or Robert appear twice?

Comment: Keep in mind also that your query is for paths that have three hops from rebecca *to* robert, so the furthest out a node can be (where that node is not rebecca or robert) is 2 hops away from one of them (as the last hop needs to be to rebecca or robert, depending on where the path started). You will never be able to get nodes that are both 2 hops away from both of them, or nodes that are 3 hops away from either of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 3 hops, the only possible way to go through the other is if (from Rebecca for this example):

`rebecca->robert->node->robert`

So robert would have to appear twice (or rebecca, from the other direction).

It seems to me that you just need a restriction that rebecca and robert must appear only once each in the path:

```
MATCH p=(rebecca:Person)-[r1*1..3]-(robert:Person)
WHERE rebecca.name=Rebecca AND robert.name='Robert'
 AND SINGLE(rebecca in nodes(p)) AND SINGLE(robert in nodes(p))
RETURN rebecca, robert,
  extract(x IN r1 | {rel: x, start: startNode(x), end: endNode(x)})
```